# Pine Script - Hide the inputs

Tags: pine-script

Is there a way to hide this from the input window?
[image]

```
len = input(5, minval=1, title="EMA_1")
src = input(close, title="Source")
out = ema(src, len)
plot(out, color=red,linewidth=1, title="EMA_1", transp=0)

len1 = input(20, minval=1, title="EMA_2")
src1 = input(close, title="Source")
out1 = ema(src1, len1)
plot(out1, color=green, title="EMA_2", transp=0)
```

Answer (score 2):

You must exclude the `input` operator

```
len = 5
src = close
out = ema(src, len)
plot(out, color=red,linewidth=1, title="EMA_1", transp=0)

len1 = 20
src1 = close
out1 = ema(src1, len1)
plot(out1, color=green, title="EMA_2", transp=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can turn off the **Arguments** in settings

[image: TradingView Settings]

reference: https://www.tradingview.com/chart/NVDA/owN9rUhT-How-to-guide-Hide-INPUT-values-of-indicators-From-Screen/