# Pine Script: how to hide `input` values from the chart?

Tags: pine-script

I have a number of `input`s that include session ranges which tend to be long strings like `"0930-1600:23456"` that then all show up over the chart. While it's helpful to have these ranges configurable to make the script flexible, the clutter in the chart is tough to stomach and largely uninteresting to the user.

[image: example of input clutter]

Is there anyway of *not* having the inputs show up over the chart, just the `plot`ted values (e.g. here the ones shown in yellow)?

If not, think of this as a feature request :)

Comment: For more complex indicators, it becomes a mess. Upvote!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment, it's not possible to regulate what inputs are displayed in the status line from inside the script (there is the `Show Indicator Arguments` option if you right-click on any indicator, but it applies to all scripts).

I've passed your request to the Pine team, thanks!

Comment: Is there any progression in switching those values off in the Status Line? Thanks. :)

Comment: I can see that this feature has been implemented, see the 'display' options now available in every input* function.

Answer (score 1):

I have found two ways:

1. In any *plot()* function call, you can use the following:

   - `plot(close, display = display.all - display.status_line)`
2. An alternative answer to your question:
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/76079720/19788371

**Nevertheless**, when I create an *input.int()* I can not seem to find a way to disable it by code.